# Вывод выбранных чекбоксов в таблице, которая внутри foreach

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach

Добрый день, друзья! Прошу помочь в написании кода. В приведенном примере checked вставится 3 раза подряд. А что если вместо "3", будет "6"? checked вставится 2 раза. Что изменить, чтобы появились все выбранные чекбоксы ?

$der - это массив чекбоксов, которые checked;

$reh - это все чекбоксы

```
$der = array(1,2,3);
$reh = array(text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6);
$table = "<table><tbody><tr>";
$i = 0;
foreach($reh as $a => $v) {
    if ($v[ad] == 'text'){
    $table .= "<td style='width: 20%;'>
        <label class='checkbox'>
        <input name='derk[]' type='checkbox' value='".$v[id]."'>
        <i></i> <span style='font-size:11px;'>".$v[ad]."</span></label></td>";
    }else{
    $table .= "<td style='width: 20%;'>
        <label class='checkbox'>
        <input name='derk[]' type='checkbox' value='".$v[id]."'";
            //знаю ошибка в след. 3 строках
            if ($v[id] == $der[$i]) {$table .= " checked=''>";}
            else{$table .= ">";}
            $i++;
    $table .= "<i></i> ".$v[ad]."</label></td>";
    }
    if(($a+1) % 5 == 0)
    $table .= "</tr><tr>";
    }
$table .= "</tr></tbody></table>"; 
echo $table;
```

Comment: если вы укажете в тегах язык программирования, то шансы на получения ответа вырастут.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию

Comment: `text1, text2`, `$v[id]`, `$v[ad]` что это все у вас такое? потеряли кавычки или `$`?

Comment: вся ваша проблема в том, что вы мешаете логику с представлением. Избавьтесь от такого. Подготовьте модель данных и используйте шаблоны. Код станет простым и понятным.

Comment: кавычки забыл во всех упомянутых местах. Главное здесь как написать код чтобы выводить checked=' ' там где надо